# Setting up Homestead.yaml and host file

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

My project is located in folder Homestead\Code\laravel6.test. I want to be able to access this project locally using the project name instead of a URL. When I run vagrant up command I get the below error:

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "d053e39e-1ae8-4358-a7ce-faf8afc01d66", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
- map: ~/code
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
 - map: laravel6.test
   to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel6.test/public
```

hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 laravel6.test
```

Comment: Do you find out any solution for this ?

Comment: I think you need to enable Virtualization in your machine's BIOS. That worked for me